# How to query conditional where clause in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to get all the Items if parameter `@ItemId = 0` else `item = @ItemId` one item

Here is what I've done

```
 ... AND (CASE WHEN @ItemId = 0 THEN Items.ItemID > 0 else
      Items.ItemID = @ItemId end )
```

Sql server gives an error in this query.

Comment: And your error is...?

Comment: It is just a general error like `incorrect syntax near > `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the logic you described:

```
...
AND (@ItemId = 0 OR Items.ItemID = @ItemID)
```

Note that your query implies something else, which you could achieve like this:

```
...
AND ((@ItemId = 0 AND Items.ItemID > 0) OR (Items.ItemID = @ItemID)
```

Comment: I am trying to get all the items if parameter is zero else get me only one item i.e. equal to parameter.

Comment: That's the first of the queries I gave.  So the `Items.ItemID > 0` component in your sample query is a bit of a red herring?